# MenuItem shortcut in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, menuitem, shortcut, controltemplate

I've got next makrup:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="65" />
<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderThickness="1" Background="Black">                 
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

                <Popup x:Name="SubMenuPopup" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right"
                            AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False">
                    <Border Background="Gray">
                        <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Background="Transparent">
                            <StackPanel Margin="0" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Background="Gray" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

When I create MenuItem somewhere and set it's Header property with "_" symbol - it doesn't create shortcut for this menu item. 
Example  - letter 'F' is not underlined and shortcut doesn't work.

How to support shortcuts in ControlTemplates in MenuItems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the complete template but instead of the TextBlock put a ContentPresenter that can recognize access keys:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
```

I suppose the xaml you have pasted here is only part of your implementation, so my solution is onl y a continuation of yours with the access key working...

You can find entire templates just like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want you menu item letter to underline itself of keypress then you have to set the InputGesture on menuitem like this:

```
      <MenuItem Header="_File" 
          InputGestureText="Ctrl+F"
          Commmand={Binding NewFileCommand}/>
```

But if you want to create shortcut for the menuitem command then you will have to create the commandbindings like below on your window:

```
      <Window.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="local:MyCommands.NewFile" Executed="NewFile_Executed" />
        </Window.CommandBindings>
        <Window.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="F" Modifiers="Control" Command="local:MyCommands.NewFile"/>
        </Window.InputBindings>
```